# Should VideoJS controls (CC, audio) appear below the video element when width gets narrow?

Tags: javascript, video, width, controls, video.js

When the width of the video is narrow, the VideoJS controls in the lower right (e.g., CC, audio, etc.) appear below the video element on the page. This can be demonstrated on the videojs.com home page by narrowing the browser window and hovering over the video to see the controls. I've tried it on IE 11 and Chrome with the same result.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there a simple way in CSS and/or JavaScript to control/detect/calculate the minimum width at which this will occur, so that I can prevent the video element width from getting small enough to have the controls appear below the video element?  Some of my videos have CC tracks, some don't. Some have enabled the playbackRates control, some don't.

I currently use the following code to resize my 16:9 videos, so ideally I'd like to enforce the minimum width here, if possible:

```
videojs("embvid", { "height": "auto", "width": "auto" }).ready(function () {
    // Get the video player object.
    var videoPlayer = this;
    // Get the player's parent element.
    var parent = document.getElementById(videoPlayer.id()).parentElement;
    // Video's aspect ratio (HD).
    var aspectRatio = 9 / 16;

    function resizeVideoJS() {
        // Find the parent's current width.
        var width = parent.offsetWidth;
        videoPlayer.width(width).height(width * aspectRatio);         
    }

    // Initialize the size by calling once.
    resizeVideoJS();
    // Call again on every resize event.
    window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;});
```

Edit: The videojs home page uses:

```
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12.5/video.js"></script>
```

and my pages use:

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
```

Both version demonstrate the same behavior on both Chrome and IE 11.

I wrapped the video element in a div and, through experimentation, set min-width to 385px in this div. That prevents the video element from getting narrow enough to have the controls appear below the element when there is a CC and a playbackRates control. But I'd prefer not to have this hard-coded.  I'd rather calculate the appropriate minimum width based on the actual threshold, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to hide overflow in the controlbar

```
.vjs-control-bar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I setup an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kuhmaty9/2/

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful to avoid displaying the overflowed controls when the player gets narrow.  I'm still interested to know if there is a way to determine the minimum player width at which controls start overflowing (or disappearing). I'd like to avoid overflowing/disappearing controls by preventing the player from getting that narrow as it's being resized.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I think it would be too complex. You'd have to account for the zoom level (since all the sizing in videojs is in em). Also what controls are show is device dependant.

I'd recommend picking a min-width based on when your video becomes to small for a reasonable user experience.

Comment: Thanks.  I did wrap the video element in a div and, through experimentation, set min-width to 385px, which seems to avoid the overflow/disappearance of controls when I have both CC and playbackRates in the control bar.  This approach deals with the problem, but I was hoping for a less hard-coded approach.

Comment: Per the suggestion here, I had also set the overflow: hidden in the vjs-control-bar, but when I upgraded to using 5.4.6 today, I found that it had the effect of clipping the tops of the seek bar position indicators (not sure what their formal name is), so I removed overflow: hidden and am just using a min-width in the div.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a browser issue. Try using video.js. (http://www.videojs.com/)

```
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
```

hope this helps

Comment: That is the exact video.js script I've been using on my pages.  The videojs.com home page uses: <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.12.5/video.js"></script>.  Both versions demonstrate the same behavior on both Chrome and IE 11.